# VS Code configuring Git Sync

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I am using Code to work on some files in a git repository, when i make some changes on a branch and one of my colleagues makes a change in the same branch *(conflicts not important)* and run the `git/sync` command it `git pull --merge` and I'd like to configure it to make something `git pull --rebase`

Can this be configured?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be configured via git config. There is no separate option in VS Code:

```
git config pull.rebase true
```

Answer (score 4):

You can now Sync+Rebase since September2018 release
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_always-rebase-when-running-sync

> The `git.rebaseWhenSync` setting will let you configure the Sync command to always use rebase instead of merge when running